# How to plot Time series with different start dates on the same graph and adjust x-axis overlapping values?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have three datasets, that look as follows:

`df_t`:

| Date | Quantity B |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-03-01 | 15 |
| 2021-03-02 | 22 |
| ... | ... |
| 2021-05-31 | 33 |

`df_c`:

| Date | Quantity C |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-03-01 | 55 |
| 2021-03-02 | 27 |
| ... | ... |
| 2021-05-31 | 94 |

And finally, I have `df_all`:

| Date | Quantity A |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-03-01 | 123 |
| 2020-03-02 | 210 |
| ... | ... |
| 2021-05-31 | 344 |

`df_all` starts on `2020-03-01`, while the other two datasets start on `2021-03-01`. I would like to plot a graph with all three datasets such that it starts on `2020-03-01` and end on the same `end`, that all share in common.

How can I do that? They all have similar quantities. I was thinking something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,9))

color = 'tab:red'
ax1.set_xlabel('Data')
ax1.plot(df_all, color=color)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)


color2 = 'tab:blue'
ax1.plot(df_t, color=color2)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color2)

color3 = 'tab:green'
ax1.set_ylabel('Quantity')
ax1.plot(df_c, color=color3)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y')
plt.show()
```

However, my graph's output, given the vast number of dates, looks as follows:
[image: Graph output]

How can I make sure that my x-axis shows the proper date times without it overlapping, and do you have any suggestions on making the lines "smoother"?

Comment: To make sure the x-axis labels don't overlap, you can define label locations using [`ax.set_xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks).

Comment: To plot lines that look smoother, you might to check [`scipy.interpolate.interp1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html.)